# How to do polymorphic queries with executeQuery() in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Why doesn't this polymorphic query work?

```
    String hql = """
                   FROM User u
                   WHERE
                   u.type.class = :typeClass
                """

    return User.executeQuery(hql, [typeClass:Super])
```

all i get is the following exception:

```
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
....
```

**Update**
The error only seems to occur when i try to add the class as a named argument. eg, i dont get an error with this code:

```
    String hql = """
                   FROM User u
                   WHERE
                   u.type.class = Super
                """

    return User.executeQuery(hql)
```

**Update2**

This issue has baffled me. And now i don't care to use any more time on it. This is what i ended up with doing:

```
    def typeClass = Super.class.name

    String hql = """
                   FROM User u
                   WHERE
                   u.type.class = $typeClass
                """

    return UserMedia.executeQuery(hql)
```

Really strange, no matter what i did when trying to pass the `class` or `class.name` i always would get the error. With and without multiline groovy string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
[typeClass: Super.class.name]
```

Edit: here is a simplified version of some code that works for me.

```
class Food {
    // ...
}

class CatFood extends Food {
    // ...
}

class DogFood extends Food {
    // ...
}

class Animal {
    static belongsTo = [food: Food] // This example is a little contrived...
}

class AnimalService {
    def usedCatFoods() {
        Animal.executeQuery("select a.food from Animal a where a.food.class = :foodClass", [foodClass: CatFood.class.name])
    }
}
```

Comment: Still same error. think it has something to do with the named property function.

Comment: I added a code example, to sanity-check that we are structuring our classes in the same way.

Comment: Ill check this out as soon as i get the time. Weird that it didn't work with me. However, do your solution still work with a multiline GString? (eg """ gstring """)

Comment: Found this in the grails documentation: Groovy multiline strings will NOT work with HQL queries

Comment: It's not very intuitive, but [Domain.executeQuery()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) accepts multi-line gstrings with no complaints. [Domain.findAll()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html) does not; if I remember correctly, you can either use a single-line string or put backslashes at the end of each line in your multi-line gstring.